# PHP / Wordpress Loop - Creating a separator

Tags: php, wordpress

I have the following function which grabs and displays the categories associated with the post, which works perfect however i want to place separators between them and not 100% sure how to achieve this. Can anyone lend me a hand?

CAT1 CAT2 CAT3

ideally would like to have like:

CAT1 / CAT2 / CAT3

Notice no seperator on the last one

PHP

```
<ul class="inline-list">
<?php 
  $id = get_the_ID();
  $cats = get_the_category($id);
  foreach ( $cats as $cat ):
?>
    <li><a href="<?php echo get_category_link($cat->cat_ID); ?>"><?php echo $cat->name; ?></a></li>
<?php
  endforeach;
?>
    <li><?php FoundationPress_entry_meta(); ?></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained by others, CSS would be the prefered way. But if you really want to do this in PHP, you could save the html code for the list to a variable, either by concatenation or output buffering:

```
ob_start();
foreach ( $cats as $cat ) {
echo '<li><a href="'.get_category_link($cat->cat_ID).'">'.$cat->name.'</a> /</li>';
}
$list = ob_get_clean();
```

Then you could remove the last 7 characters (`" /</li>"`) using the substr function and put "`</li>`" back before outputting the code:

```
echo substr($list, 0, -7).'</li>;
```

Comment: CSS is my preference as well but client requirements :( anyway that worked a treat! thanks very much for that!

Answer (score 0):

To do this in your code you can simply do the following:

```
<ul class="inline-list">
<?php 
  $id = get_the_ID();
  $cats = get_the_category($id);
  foreach ( $cats as $cat ):
?>
    <li><a href="<?php echo get_category_link($cat->cat_ID); ?>"><?php echo $cat->name; ?></a></li>
<?php
  endforeach;
?>
    <li class="no-border"><?php FoundationPress_entry_meta(); ?></li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
ul.inline-list li{
  border-right:1px solid #eee;
}
ul.inline-list li.no-border{
  border-right:none;
}
```

---

Alternatively, you can achieve this using `nth-child`, `first-child` or `last-child` CSS selectors.

For example:

```
ul.inline-list li {
  border-left:1px solid #eee;
}
ul.inline-list li:first-child{
  border-left:none;
}
```

This code sets a light-grey border to the left of all the `li`s.  The second statement then removes the border from the *first* `li`.

The same can be achieved with `border-right` and `last-child` (removing the border from the *last* `li`).

---

In both cases you can use CSS for the separator, whether that's a border, a background or by using `before` to add a <kbd>/</kbd> character.

Answer (score 0):

mikemike's answer is a perfect solution but if for some reason you want to do it using code you could try this.

```
<ul class="inline-list">
<?php 
 $id = get_the_ID();
 $cats = get_the_category($id);
 $count = 1;
 foreach ( $cats as $cat ):
?>
<li><a href="<?php echo get_category_link($cat->cat_ID); ?>"><?php echo $cat->name; ?></a> </li>
<?php
 if($count < count($cats)):
   echo '/';
 endif;
$count++;
endforeach;
?>
<li><?php FoundationPress_entry_meta(); ?></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can count how many iterations you have done, and if less that the total, output the separator:

```
$count = count($cats);
$i = 0;
foreach ( $cats as $cat ):?>
    <li>
        <a href="<?php echo get_category_link($cat->cat_ID); ?>"><?php echo $cat->name; ?></a>
        <?php echo ++$i < $count ? '/' : '';?>
    </li>
<?php endforeach;
```

Live example: http://codepad.viper-7.com/7QU7x9

Comment: This won't work, there are `li`s outside of the loop.  You also have a syntax error.

Comment: @mikemike The list elements outside the loop appear to be unrealated. And what syntax error?

Answer (score 0):

If you solely want to do this in php, I'd change from a foreach loop to a for loop, then you can decipher between the two.

IE:

```
$length = count($cat);
for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
    $cat = $cats[i];
    if ($i + 1 == $length) {?>
        <li><a href="<?php echo get_category_link($cat->cat_ID); ?>"><?php echo $cat->name; ?></a></li>
    <?php } else { ?>
        <li><a href="<?php echo get_category_link($cat->cat_ID); ?>"><?php echo $cat->name; ?></a> / </li>
    <?php }
}
```